# How to show whether a set in a normed vector space is compact or not?

Tags: real-analysis

I've tried looking for similar problems but couldn't find any. So here it is. We have a normed vector space $\mathcal{l}_p = \{ x= (x_1, x_2, \cdots) : \sum_{n=1}^\infty |x_n|^p \lt \infty \}$, with norm $\|x\|_p =(\sum_{n=1}^\infty |x_n|^p)^\frac1p $. Is the set $A=\{x\in \mathcal{l_3} :|x_n|^3 \leq \frac1n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ compact in $\mathcal{l_3}$?

I've tried to prove that it is compact but I'm not getting anywhere. Any suggestions on how to proceed are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the sequence $x^m=(1,\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{2}},\ldots,\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{m}},0,0\ldots)$, for $m\in \Bbb N^*$ $x^m\in A$, and show that for $p>2q$ $\|x^p-x^{q}\|_3\geq \dfrac{1}{\sqrt[3]{2}}$. Hence there is no convergent subsequence of $(x^m)_m$.  $A$ is not compact.

Answer (score 0):

However, your criterion is **almost** true.  If you have a sequence $M_n$ of positive numbers with $\sum M_n < \infty$, then
$$
\{x \in l_3\; : |x_n| \le M_n \text{ for all } n;\}
$$
is compact.  So in the sense that $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ **almost** converges, you are **almost** right.